# Javascript check two dates

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
var fromDate = new Date('2015-05-21T10:17:28.593Z')
var endDate = new Date()
```

I have from date and end date.How to check from date is ascending or descending than end date?.any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are trying to check if fromDate is later than endDate. You can just use the standard comparison operator and it will work just fine.

```js
var fromDate = new Date('2015-05-21T10:17:28.593Z').getTime();
var endDate = new Date().getTime();
var isFromDateAscending = fromDate > endDate;

console.log(isFromDateAscending);
```

Comment: Really? Could you show me what you have? It works fine for me

Comment: @arunrajesh The `<` operator should work just fine, as long as both objects contain the date you think they do (and, if they don't, you have a different problem).

Comment: @D-reaper its always better to use `.getTime()` to compare dates. I guess modern browsers have added handling for them.

Comment: @Rajesh oh yea I forgot about that. Yea it is better because it is converted to a number, which is easier to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```js
    var fromDate = new Date('2015-05-21T10:17:28.593Z')
    var endDate = new Date() 
    if (fromDate > endDate) {
        alert("FromDate is Ascending")
    }else{
        alert("EndDate is Ascending")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be using `MomentJS` for date checking/parsing/manipulation as it has a very good API and helps deal with unexpected hitches that the native `Date` interface can expose.

```
//Import moment
import * as moment from 'moment';

//In your file somewhere

if (moment().isAfter(moment('2015-05-21T10:17:28.593Z'))) {
  //Current time is after the fromDate
} else {
  //fromDate is after current time
}
```

It also has a bunch of display utilities etc. that can help when dealing with times (and timezones). [You can check the documentation here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var date1 = new Date("7/11/2010");
var date2 = new Date("8/11/2010");
var diffDays = parseInt((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

alert(diffDays )
```

diffDays is the answer u desire